# Making a link from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, url

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to extract from a string **the first** *URL* or *e-mail address* and then use the *resulting string* (examples: "`http://www.test.com`", "`mailto:test@test.com`", ...) as the `href` attribute value used in a HTML  `<a href="resulting_string_value">Test link name</a>`.

**How can I do that in the safest way?**

P.S.: [I know the RoR `auto_link` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-auto_link), but that does not accomplish what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you probably didn't want a regular expression, but it works, and you might use it as a helper

The code for urls:

```
str = "http://someurl.com/"
str.scan(/http:\/\/([^\/]*)/)
```

The code for emails:

```
str = "mailto:someemail@email.com"
str.scan(/mailto:([^ ]*)/)
```

Putting it all together:

```
result_array = str.scan(/mailto:([^ ]*)|http:\/\/([^\/]*)/)
if result_array.length > 0
  result = result[0][0] unless empty? result[0][0] 
  result = result[0][1] unless empty? result[0][1] 
end
```

Comment: Oh sorry, where you wrote safest I read fastest, but the answers is still valid

Comment: sorry, `null?` ? What is this magical method of which you speak?

Comment: I have thought of "nil?" and wrote "null?", but apparently I confused with the method "empty?". Sorry for that, editing the answer

Answer (score 1):

Domain and host names can have `-` or `.` characters in them and email usernames have a system-specific definition. Here is a hURL matcher that tries to share the DNS parse.

```
/((https*\:\/\/)|(mailto:[^@]+@))(\/*[\w\-rb.]+)*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the first link in the string, you can just use match.  Also, you want to use a non-greedy match:

```
str.match(/mailto:([^ ]*?( |$|\n))|http:\/\/([^\/]*?)( |$|\n)/)
```

You can add more checking for valid email addresses, etc. if you'd like.

Once you've got the string, you can use auto_link to make a link from it.